# Call custom method on keypress SlickGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I am using slickgrid to display certain data. How can i add custom method to slickgrid rows ?

For eg: I want to open modal box with current row data whenever enter key is pressed.

Comment: give us any code, also it good to make jsfiddle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can subscribe to the `onKeyDown` event in the grid to check this. Something like:

```
grid.onKeyDown.subscribe(function(e) {
   if (e.which == 13) {
      // open modal window
   }
});
```

Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If i got your requirement well, then try out this code,

```
createInvoiceDetailsTable : function () {
    var gridOptions, gridColumns;

    gridColumns = [
        {id:'ean_code', name:'EAN', field:'ean_code', width:125, cssClass: 'grid-cell'},
        {id:'description', name:'Product Description', field:'description', width:250, formatter:opr.invoice.productGridDescriptionFormatter, cssClass: 'grid-cell'},
        {id:'qty', name:'Qty', field:'qty', width:40, , formatter:UpdateQtyBtnFormatter},
    ];



    gridOptions = {
        editable: true,
        autoEdit: true,
        enableAddRow: false,
        enableCellNavigation: true,
        asyncEditorLoading: false,
        enableColumnReorder: false,
        rowHeight: 35
    };

    dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView();
    invoiceProductGrid = new Slick.Grid($('#invoice_details_grid_div'), dataView , gridColumns, gridOptions);

    function UpdateQtyBtnFormatter (row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
        return '<input type="button" style="width:30px; height:30px;" class="update_invoice_product_qty" id="' + value + '" value="Q"/>';
}
}
```

Using this `update_invoice_product_qty` class name you can write event.

If this is not your requirement then please share with some code or procedure which you tried earlier.